# How to check if string exists before doing a POST/PUT request?

Tags: javascript, vuejs2

I am using VueJS and I got a web form where a user can check an html checkbox labeled "Active" to designate whether an item (named `branch`) is `active`. If the input box is left unchecked, that means the item is `inactive`. IF a `branch` is `inactive`, I dynamically append the text `(inactive)` to the `branch` property. The data collection from the form is then sent to a database/remote api. Pretty straightforward. UI examples below:

[image] [image]

My question is: 
**How can I REMOVE the string `(inactive)` from the branch name if it already exists?**

Here's my `data()` object and relevant `method()`:

```
  data() {
    return {
      branch: {
        division_id: null,
        branch: '',
        active: false,
        branch_id: null
      },

onSubmitUpdate() {
      this.loading = true
      let branchEdit = this.branch
      branchEdit.branch = this.branch.active ? this.branch.branch : this.branch.branch + ' (inactive)'
      ApiService.updateBranch(branchEdit)
        .then(() => {
          this.loading = false
          //this.$router.push({ path: '/home' })
        })
```

Thanks for any tips on how I can do this efficiently!

Comment: make a copy of it, don't make changes to the original branch object, to the clone one instead. eg. let branchEdit = Object.assign({}, this.branch);

Comment: Can u provide some code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [`String.prototype.replace()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace) to replace the string if it exists.

```
branchEdit.branch = this.branch.active ? 
    this.branch.branch.replace(' (inactive)', '') : 
    this.branch.branch + ' (inactive)';
```

If branch name contains the string `(inactive)`, it is removed. If not, nothing is changed.

Answer (score 0):

don't have to make changes to the original `the.branch` object. 
create a temp clone of it, post to the API, then done.

```
onSubmitUpdate() {
      this.loading = true
      // clone it
      let clone = Object.assign({}, this.branch)
      clone.branch = clone.active ? clone.branch : clone.branch + ' (inactive)'
      ApiService.updateBranch(clone)
      .....
}
```

if you want to display `branch + " (inactive)"` in web page, since you are using vue.js. use `v-if` would work:

```
<span v-if="!branch.active">(inactive)</span>
```

Comment: The problem is when a user unchecks and checks a checkbox again, branch name contains `(inactive)` text.

Comment: it doesn't. `(inactive)` was appended to the temp object `clone.branch`, not to the original `this.branch`. so `this.branch.branch` keeps not changed.

Comment: well if you need to display the altered text to user, that's only a part of the solution. I mean, to append a suffix to a string is not a good practice. I'd let the branch.branch to be immutable and find another way to display `branch + " (inactive)"`.

Comment: I don't think that appending a suffix to a string is a bad practice. But in this case I agree that modifying branch name to display `(inactive)` text isn't good. But looks like OP just wants to change the data before making the API request.